# PrimeNG p-dropdown options from an array inside an object

Tags: angular, primeng

I have object that contains lots of data relevant to the page and I would like to set the p-dropdown to an subArray within this object, is this possible?

Example of object:

```
this.tempHouse = {
  houses: [
    {
      house: 'House 1',
      houseId: '123',
    },
    {
      house: 'House 2',
      houseId: '456',
    },
  ],
}
```

Example of the HTML p-dropdown:

```
<p-dropdown [options]="tempHouse" optionLabel="houses.house" optionValue="houses.houseId"></p-dropdown>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please try this:

```
<p-dropdown [options]="tempHouse.houses" optionLabel="house" optionValue="houseId"></p-dropdown>
```

Comment: Hi Mateusz Ścigała
I tried this originally and it did not through an error but the page does not render correctly.  I tried the alternative to bind options="{{ tempHouse.houses }}" and this did not work either. Thanks

Comment: Just working back through my emails, and this works now I must of made an error in my code. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

try this.

```
<p-dropdown [options]="tempHouse?.houses" optionLabel="house" optionValue="houseId"></p-dropdown>
```

Comment: Sorry the above answer did work, as did this.  Must of been an error in my code. Thanks